# What is wrong with how im using this query builder? I'm able to get the records back but it does not order the items

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I'm using knex and postgres

I have this handler that calls this query builder.  I am able to retrieve the records, however they are not sorting correctly.

What i have:

```
getStuff(req) {
...

return (toSqlName, builder) => 
  builder.whereRaw(`${toSqlName('id')} = ANY(?::uuid[]`, [ids]).orderByRaw('username DESC')
}
```

Seems to work fine except the records coming back are not sorted.  I've tried chaining `.orderBy('username', 'desc')` as well.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the query string generated by `knex`

Comment: have you selected  username column?